# gerrit: use LDAP auth and have a gerrit-local account for Jenkins

Tags: gerrit

We a new gerrit 2.2.1 server using LDAP authentication in our corporate environment.  We also have a Jenkins server running as a local UNIX jenkins user that I want to get check in with gerrit and post build results into gerrit.

We don't have a "jenkins" LDAP account, and even if we did, the systems group doesn't give out passwords for system accounts, so I can't go into the web UI, create the account and add jenkins' publich ssh key.  How I can add a "jenkins" account to gerrit that Jenkins can use?  We already have a number of people registered in Gerrit, so I need to be careful with any operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little more Google searching found [Paulo Pires's blog post](http://ppires.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/gerrit-jenkins-in-ldap-environment/), which led to using Gerrit's [create-account](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-create-account.html) command.